# How to Implement a UISearchBar if Table View Cells are Custom Data Types

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, filter, uisearchbar

In all of the UISearchBar implementation tutorials I've seen, the table view cells are sourced from a simple array of text. I'm having difficulty implementing the Search Bar, when:

1. My table view cells are sourced from a custom class (the custom cell contains multiple elements)
2. I want to search/filter by one of the String properties of that custom class

Also to note, I'm sourcing my data from Firestore.

This is my view controller that displays the table view I want to filter.

```
import UIKit

class MealPlanViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    private var model = MealPlanModel()
    private var mealPlan = [MealPlan]()
    private var isStarFiltered = false
    var filteredData: [MealPlan]!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var starButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationItem.title = "Menu"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        
        // Set ViewController as the datasource and delegate of the tableView
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        // Use MealPlanModel to get the mealPlans from the JSON File
        model.delegate = self
        
        searchBar.delegate = self
        
        filteredData = mealPlan
        
        // Set the status of the Star Button
        setStarFilterButton()
        
        // Retrieve all Meal Plans according to the filter status
        if isStarFiltered {
            model.getMealPlans(true)
        }
        else {
            model.getMealPlans()
        }
        
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        // Detect the indexPath the user selected
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        
        // Check that the indexPath isn't nil
        guard indexPath != nil else {
            // The user hasn't selected anything
            return
        }
        
        // Get the mealPlan the user selected
        let mealPlanSelected = mealPlan[indexPath!.row]
        
        // Get a reference to the InstructionViewController
        let ingredientsVC = segue.destination as! IngredientsViewController
        
        // Get a reference to the currentMealPlanIndex in the InstructionViewController - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers
        ingredientsVC.currentMealPlanIndex = indexPath!.row
        
    }
    
    func setStarFilterButton() {

        let imageName = isStarFiltered ? "star.fill" : "star"
        starButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: imageName), for: .normal)

    }
    
    @IBAction func starButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        // Toggle the star filter status
        isStarFiltered.toggle()
        
        // Run the query
        if isStarFiltered {
            model.getMealPlans(true)
        }
        else {
            model.getMealPlans()
        }
        
        // Update the starButton
        setStarFilterButton()
        
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        
        filteredData = []
        
        if searchText == "" {
            filteredData = mealPlan
        }
        else {
            for item in mealPlan {
                
                if ((item.title?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) != nil) {
                    
                    filteredData.append(item)
                    
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    
    
    
    
}

extension MealPlanViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mealPlan.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // Get a cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MealPlanCell", for: indexPath) as! MealPlanCell
        
        // Get the mealPlan that the tableView is asking about
        let mealPlanInTable = mealPlan[indexPath.row]
        
        // Customize the cell
        cell.displayMealPlan(mealPlanInTable)
        
        // Round the corners
        cell.mealPlanView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.coverImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
        // Return the cell
        return cell
        
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
    }
    
}

extension MealPlanViewController: MealPlanProtocol {
    
    func mealPlansRetrieved(mealPlans: [MealPlan]) {
        
        print("MealPlan retrieved from model (MealPlanViewController).")
        
        // Set the mealPlans property of the ViewController to the mealPlans passed back from the model
        self.mealPlan = mealPlans
        
        // Refresh the tableView
        tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    
}
```

This is my custom cell:

```
class MealPlanCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeSourceLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var estimatedTimeLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var coverImageView: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mealPlanView: UIView!
    
    var mealPlanToDisplay:MealPlan?
    
    func displayMealPlan(_ mealPlan:MealPlan) {
        
        // Keep a reference to the mealPlan
        mealPlanToDisplay = mealPlan
        
        // Set the titleLabel
        titleLabel.text = mealPlanToDisplay!.title
        
        // Set the numberOfRecipesLabel
        recipeSourceLabel.text = mealPlanToDisplay!.recipeSource
        
        // Set the estimatedTimeLabel
        estimatedTimeLabel.text = mealPlanToDisplay!.estimatedTime
        
        // Set the coverImageView
        if mealPlanToDisplay!.coverImageView == nil {
            return
        }
        coverImageView.image = UIImage(named: mealPlanToDisplay!.coverImageView!)
        
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

And this is the struct that is returned in my `displayMealPlan` function:

```
struct MealPlan {
    
    var docID:String?
    var title:String?
    var recipeSource:String?
    var estimatedTime:String?
    var coverImageView:String?
    var isStarred:Bool?
    
}
```

The project is building without error, but nothing happens when I type in the search bar. I'm thinking it could be a couple of things but am not sure:

1. I have to change the return values in my `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` methods to return the filtered data
2. Filtering by `item.title` is incorrect methodology

Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you have the correct methodology. Have you tried using break points to see what elements of your code aren't getting hit? Also, using print statements to make sure your variables are what you think they are (and not nil or something else)?

Comment: @SanzioAngeli Thank you for the tip! I used `print(filteredData!)` after `self.tableView.reloadData()` and it seems like it's not filtering for the data I type in the UISearchBar - i.e., my print function returns the entire unfiltered array,